# How to ensure uniqueness when elasticsearch is inserted in multithreading？

Tags: java, elasticsearch, concurrency, insert, unique

We have some documents of elasticsearch . The uniqueness of the document is determined by some fields together, how to ensure uniqueness when java multi-threading determines whether it exists and is inserted.

I didn't know what good method I had before, so I wrote a method: I guess if it exists, if it doesn't exist, I insert it, and this method is modified by syncronized. But I found this to be a very inefficient practice.

```
/**
 * @param document
 */
synchronized void selectAndInsert(Map<String, Object> document){
    //Determine if it exists, insert it if it does not exist
}
```

My mapping is as follows:
{"properties":{"pt_number":{ "type":"keyword" }, "pt_name":{"type":"keyword" },"pt_longitude":{ "type":"text"},"pt_latitude":{"type":"text" },"rd_code":{ "type":"text" }, "rd_name":{ "type":"keyword"}, "area_code":{ "type":"keyword"} ... and so on }}

Uniqueness is determined by area_code, pt_longitude and pt_latitude. When the document is inserted, I will judge whether it exists according to area_code, pt-longitude, pt_latitude, and insert if it does not exist. How do I guarantee the uniqueness of a document when java multithreading is running?

This question has plagued me for some time. Who can help me, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee there isn't such document just by properties in index in any way. Even if you check it's presence in index and don't see it, there is some time between response for that operation was issued and your indexing request accepted by ES.

So basically you have only two ways:

- Guarantee single execution of indexing operation (long and not-so-easy way because we don't have exactly-once systems)
- Convert document unique properties into document ID, so even if your indexing operations overlap, they will just write same values into same document (or the second one and following will fail, depending on request options).

The latter one is quite easy, you have some options out of the box:

- Take all unique properties in determined order and concatenate their string representations (ugly)
- Take all unique properties in determined order, concatenate their byte values and encode using Base64 (less ugly)
- Take all unique properties in determined order, pass them through hashing function (md5, sha-X families, whatever you like) and use string representation of result.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think the second solution may be the most appropriate. In my current project, I may need some time to reset the document _id. Fortunately, document _id has not been widely used in projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you detect an insert why not once insertion done (and index refresh...) check if you have no duplicate. A second solution would be to write every Xs using a bulk insert-update pack of data (= store new documents in a list in a share area, so you could check if your document arenot already present in, and write this list every 10s for example).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will think about whether this is suitable for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Common scenario might be that you have documents sent in some way (ex. kafka) and wish to ensure there are no duplicates. As far as I know there is no such a way in ElasticSearch though you might try a trick here:

- ElasticSearch allows custom document ID to be given
- Document ID is restricted to 512 bytes length and cannot be used for normal "processing"

You might wish to create an ID based on your fields (like primary key in a database). If using _create then your document would be created only if it doesn't exist yet.

Some problems are still to be solved though:
How to generate the ID? Simple concatenation would work but only if you are sure the total length won't exceed 512B. Otherwise a checksum can be used - but there is a small chance of collision.
What to do if almost the same document is received (your keys are the same but some other difference exists). Elastic would allow only "replace" or "do not replace". You need to handle other scenarios.